# iOS extracting certificate identity: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, xcode, ssl

I'm developing an iOS application and struggling to extract an identity from a .p12 certificate. I'm still new to objective-c so I'm sure something major is missing. Here's the code:

```
@implementation P12Extractor

-(SecIdentityRef)getIdentity{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ServerCert" ofType:@"p12"];
NSData *p12data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
CFDataRef inP12Data = (__bridge CFDataRef)p12data;
SecIdentityRef myIdentity;

OSStatus status = extractIdentity(inP12Data, &myIdentity);

if (status != 0) {
    NSLog(@"%@",status);
}
return myIdentity;

}

OSStatus extractIdentity(CFDataRef inP12Data, SecIdentityRef *identity){
OSStatus securityError = errSecSuccess;

CFStringRef password = CFSTR("password");
const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
const void *values[] = { password };

CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);

CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inP12Data, options, &items);

if (securityError == 0) {
    CFDictionaryRef ident = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items,0); // <<<at this point i get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,adress=0x0) error
    const void *tempIdentity = NULL;
    tempIdentity = CFDictionaryGetValue(ident, kSecImportItemIdentity);
    *identity = (SecIdentityRef)tempIdentity;
}

if (options) {
    CFRelease(options);
}

return securityError;
}

@end
```

I've marked the point of error with a comment, I really have no idea why I keep getting this. This code should be the approved solution from Apple dev site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is still empty when you try to get its first element...

```
 CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
 securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inP12Data, options, &items);

 if (securityError == 0) {
   CFDictionaryRef ident = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items,0); // <<<at this point i get an   EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,adress=0x0) error
```

I think the problem could lay with the certificate or with the options you pass in.

Comment: Can you please explain how you solved it? Same issue here and you accepted but didn't say how this solved your problem

Comment: This is not the right answer - same problem here - and I do a check beforehand: guard CFArrayGetCount(items) > 0 else { return nil }

Comment: The problem is with `SecPKCS12Import`. It should not be the case that `securityError` is 0 while `items` is not correctly filled up... as I wrote, check the certificate or the options you pass in.